# Getting 499 status from nginx log upto 2 minutes in every 3 hours interval, when memcache restarts

Tags: nginx, mysql, centos7, php-fpm, memcached

I have two Application servers served by an another haproxy load balancer server. The application servers are connected with a memcache server and a mysql database server.
I am observing in every 3 hours interval more than 50% traffic gets 499 status upto 2 minutes. I can't understand the reason why this error occurs in an interval of time. I also noticed in every 3 hours a 'memcache restart' cron runs in memcache server. So, I am guessing this is the reason behind the 499 error.

Now my question is if the 'memcache service restart' is the reason behind the 499 scenario then why and how it occurs as we know if the memcache service is unavailable then the traffic should serve by the database server? How can we minimized the error?

And if memcache restart isn't the reason behind this 499 error then what could be the possible reasons for that and how can we overcome it?

Comment: 499 means that the web browser disconnected before nginx could send a response. It is probably a very bad idea to restart memcached.

Comment: Could you post the last 400 lines of your nginx log with the 499 status?  Also, consider implementation of some part of this url for memcache error logging to get the details from the memcache perspective.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ha-memcached-using-logs.html